# Is it possible to use a custom test url for testing when running server using Python/Django on Windows?

Tags: python, django

I am used to PHP / Apache as I can add an entry in the Windows Hosts file and access that instead of using localhost url. For example,

`Windows > hosts file > 127.0.0.1   testsite.test`

and then I add this `testsite.test` in the Apache VirtualHost directive too.

I am new to Python and Django and have been following a tutorial where it showed me how to setup Python an Django, and set up a virtual environment. After setting it up, it run `python manage.py runserver` that launched the default page on http://127.0.0.1:8000

Is it possible to access this url same as Apache above?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different options. The first one is to run Django runserver on port 80, by executing `python manage.py runserver 80`. This one may require administration privileges on some systems, and should be avoided in such case, as giving the privileges to your development code may be a security issue (you can destroy your OS by mistake or someone may get control over your operating system remotely).

2nd option is to redirect your web server through nginx or apache. A simple configuration file for nginx:

```
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name example.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or custom domain name
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;  # Adjust to your need

    location /media  {
        alias /path/to/your/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files
    }

    location /static {
        alias /path/to/your/mysite/static; # your Django project's collected static files
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include     /etc/nginx/proxy_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look into this. Is this per site config? (As I could add all sites in just one vhosts files with Apache)

Comment: It's per-site config. Usually, default nginx configuration files will give you an option to create separate files per site to keep everything more organized. You can just copy and paste this whole snipped into a separate file and put it in the correct location. The exact location will depend on the way you've installed your nginx.